# Error while trying to compute Dask dataframe from sql

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I created a Dask dataframe using read_sql_query method and when I try to compute (some operation like pivoting, require computing), it raises an SQL error stating that it did not find the column I initially set as index.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

from dask.dataframe import read_sql_query

import dask as dk
from sqlalchemy import sql

import urllib

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_string)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

url_str = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params


def _remove_leading_select_from_query(query):
    if query.startswith("SELECT "):
        return query.replace("SELECT ", "", 1)
    else:
        return query
    




def query_sql_to_dataframe(conn_string, query,index):
    try:
        conection = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
        sa_query = sql.select(sql.text(_remove_leading_select_from_query(query)))
        df = read_sql_query(sa_query, url_str,index_col=index)

    except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        df = None 

    finally:
        if conection :
            conection .close()

    return df


# FT_DOC_ELETRONICO
query = 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_column ASC) AS row,* FROM dbo.my_table'

idx = "row"
doc_eletr = query_sql_to_dataframe(conn_string, query,index=idx)
```

All the data operations work fine but when I need to compute the dataframe, it raises an eror as follows:

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'row'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'row'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statements could not be prepared (8180)")
> [SQL: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_column ASC) AS row,* FROM dbo.my_table
> WHERE row >= ? AND row <= ?]
> [parameters: (1, 1181321)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

I tried changing the column but every column I set as index, Dask raises the same error claiming, it did not find it. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: When you set the `index_col` parameter in the `read_sql_query` function, it tries to use that column as an index for the resulting Dask DataFrame. However, Dask expects the specified index column to be present in the underlying Pandas DataFrame, which might not be the case when using SQL expressions directly.

To work around this issue, you can reset the index of the Dask DataFrame after reading the data using `reset_index` method. This will remove the index, and you can perform your computations without any SQL-related issues.

Comment: Even after using `reset_index` method on the dataframe, the computation still raises the same error.

Comment: When you create the alias for the row number, your alias contains the * symbol: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY some_column ASC) AS row,*`. Is it possible to use `row,*` as an alias?

Comment: Dask is trying to partition the data it reads using the index you gave to it, row in this case. But there is no row columns in your database. Dask adds this to your query: WHERE row >= ? AND row <= ?.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási When i set `row,*`,  the `*` is the operator for selecting all, not part of the alias. When I run the same query on DBeaver, for example, it returns the `row` as a created index column, no issues.